# Why do my Batch Requests increase when doing a Differential Backup

Tags: sql-server, performance, backup

I have started doing some long-term tracking of various activities on our 2012 SQL Server and I have noticed an increase in Batch Requests during our incremental backups.

To give an idea, normal day-to-day we are around 10-20 batch requests per second but during the time our differential backup runs, it jumps to 100-130 per second.

I know this is not a lot but it made me curious as to what is going on that it increases 10-fold.

Not sure what info you might need to help troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 2):

After monitoring the active sessions and queries during the high activity period, I have come to the conclusion that the third party software we use (LiteSpeed) to perform backups is the culprit.

There seems to be a lot of queries to get information about the maintenance plan, updating backup statistics, getting information about the server and the database, etc. This server is not only the one being backed up at this time but it is also the "Central Repository" for all our servers.

It appears I jumped the gun by posting here but at least this might prevent others from spinning their wheels on something that does not appear to be a real issue or one you can do anything about, other than not using the third party software. If our environment becomes bogged because of this, I would bet moving the "Central Repository" to another server would reduce the load on this one.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny because I had a question kind of similar to that today for which @kin posted a really good answer:

[What is the use of restore headeronly when performing a backup?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123969/what-is-the-use-of-restore-headeronly-when-performing-a-backup)

You'll find a way to see what SSMS is doing :)